# I have an old server in my finder

Tags: macbook-pro, network

I can see in my finder this server: [image]

I want to delete it, does somebody know how it could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

First, in Finder, check: Go > Connect to Server > (click the three dots) > and select clear recent servers.

Alternatively, if you simply want it to disappear, go to Finder preferences > General > deselect "Connected servers"

Comment: None of both worked, I can still see it in my finder : S @rodcodes